# How to snapshot schema and data from a different database and different schema on DBT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snapshot, dbt

running my sources on DBT, it returns the following error:

```
18:32:41  Encountered an error:
Compilation Error in snapshot customer_snapshot (snapshots\customer.sql)
  Snapshot 'snapshot.myproject._customer_snapshot' (snapshots\customer.sql) depends on a source named 'myschema.customer' which was not found
```

The message is correct. There is no such schema in the database. Schema, tables and data are present in another DB.

Assuming, I'm in a sandbox, how would I snapshot schema and data from a different db, different schema, using DBT?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this only works because Snowflake databases are just logical databases that share a connection. This will not work on other dbt adapters.

First you configure a [source](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/sources) that specifies the database:

```yaml
# models/sources.yml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: myschema # dbt also uses this as the schema name unless you provide a schema property
    database: other_db
    tables:
      - name: customer
```

Then in your [snapshot](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/snapshots), you can reference this source:

```sql
{% snapshot customer_snapshot %}
{{
    config(
      target_database='analytics',
      target_schema='snapshots',
      unique_key='id',

      strategy='timestamp',
      updated_at='updated_at',
    )
}}
select * from {{ source('myschema', 'customer') }}
{% endsnapshot %}
```